# Global CORS configuration using Java Config is not working in Spring MVC

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-mvc, axios, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to enbale CROS globally for all the my Rest API developed in project and for the same i have tried doing the same
with Global CORS configuration using Java Config.
Following is the configuration class with @Configuration annotation.

```
package com.fs;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.fs")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter 
{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
           
      registry.addMapping("/**")
          .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
          .allowedMethods("POST", "GET",  "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE")
          .allowedHeaders("X-Auth-Token", "Content-Type")        
          .maxAge(4800);
    }
}
```

Now , i am trying to hit below API using AX from react application running on  https://localhost:3000 , but it's not providing Response and producing Network Error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8089/ewamftrxnsws/purchase/getSchemeList' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
let requestUrl = "http://localhost:8089/ewamftrxnsws/purchase/getSchemeList";
let promiseResponse = axios.post(requestUrl,{
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
       });
    promiseResponse.then(res=>{
        let isSuccess = res.data;
}).catch( error =>{
        console.log( "MFSchemeListApi catch => "+error);        
    });
```

What is the problem ? Thanks.

Comment: As clearly stated , you need to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in your configuration .

Comment: added the same in congiguration as followed but still not working .allowedHeaders("X-Auth-Token", "Content-Type","Access-Control-Allow-Origin") @Umeshwaran

Comment: Try `allowedMethods("*")..allowedHeaders("*")` instead of `.allowedMethods("POST", "GET",  "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE").allowedHeaders("X-Auth-Token", "Content-Type")`

Comment: still not working , though controller level Config is working `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")` @Umeshwaran

Comment: Please see my answer . It may help resolve your issue. Give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be because of deprecated "WebMvcConfigurerAdapter " . Try using "WebMvcConfigurer " .

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(
                        "http://localhost:3000",..)
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD")
                .allowCredentials(true)
        ;
    }

}
```

This should bring back the "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" header into the request.

Hope this resolves your issue . Give it a try!!!

Answer (score 0):

from: https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

If you are using Spring Security, make sure to enable CORS at Spring Security level as well to allow it to leverage the configuration defined at Spring MVC level.

`@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()...
    }
}`